# How to see which channels has audio in a 5.1 audio track

Tags: windows-10, audio

I have a 5.1 audio file. I know that music is only present on some of the channels (for example, music is only on the front left and right and surround left and right (there is no audio in the centre of sub)).

I have no ability to play 5.1 audio, as I only have a stereo out on my sound card.

How can I tell which channels have audio?

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in any audio editor? I have never worked with 5.1 files, but I suppose loading audio file into a program like Audacity should show you which channels are silent.

Comment: As it looks like no native way to do this in Windows, can you move to an answer @gronostaj. When I import it as an audio file into Cubase I have the option to split each channel into a track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the file in some audio editor, like [Audacity](http://www.audacityteam.org/). It should show all channels side by side, letting you see which are silent.

If you use Cubase 7, it will give you the option to import each channel as separate tracks